# Find bug in the C Program to Reverse a String

Tags: c, debugging

I have written the following code to reverse a String. But it is giving some error. It get stuck after calling the `reverseStr()` function. I am unable to find the bug. Can someone help me?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
char * reverseStr(char *str){
    int i,len = 0;
    while(str[len]!=NULL){
        len++;         
    }
    len-=1;char temp;
    for(i=0;i<len/2;i++){
        //printf("%d %d %s\n",i,len,str);
        temp = str[len-i];
        str[len-i]=str[i];
        str[i]=temp;
        //printf("%d %d %s\n",i,len,str);
    }
    return str;
}

int main(void) {
    char *str = "abcdefg";

    printf("Original :: %s\n",str);
    str = reverseStr(str);
    printf("Reversed :: %s",str);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Compile with all warnings and debug info (`gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`). Then **use the debugger** (`gdb`)

Comment: @mav3n if you uncomment the `printf` in the `for` loop, does they print out anything?

Comment: @Jonathan I don't know what exactly the error is. I mentioned it got stuck after calling the reverseStr() function. That is what my question is. What is the bug? It just displays `Original :: abcdefg` and First Occurrence of the for loop inside reverseStr() function.

Comment: @SSC it prints for the first time only

Answer (score 2):

```
char *str = "abcdefg";
```

will place string literal "abcdefg" in the read-only section of the memory and making `str` to point to that, any writing operation on this memory illegal and hence the runtime error.

Use `char str[] = "abcdefg" ;` and simply `reverseStr(str);`

Now you can't do `str = reverseStr(str) ;` here since types are different, you can store the result in another char pointer though.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void reverseStr(char *str){
    int i,len;
    len = strlen(str);
    char temp1,temp2;
    int j = len - 1;
    for(i=0;i<j/2 + j%2;i++){
        printf("%d %d %s\n",i,j,str);
        temp1 = str[j-i];
        temp2 = str[i];
        str[i]=temp1;
        str[j-i]=temp2;
        printf("%d %d %s\n",i,j,str);
    }
    return;
}

int main(void) {
    char str[10];
    strcpy(str,"abcdefgh");

    printf("Original :: %s\n",str);
    reverseStr(str);
    printf("Reversed :: %s",str);

    return 0;
}
```